# global exception handling with nlog

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, nlog

Is there a way blog can capture all exception without specifying a try catch? For example going to a page that is not available on a MVC website and picking up an error in Icontroller and capturing page not found. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NLog does not *capture* errors in your application. It allows you to *log* captured errors.

See [Exception Handling in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422572/Exception-Handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC) or [Global Error Handling in ASP.NET MVC](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/12/01/GlobalErrorHandlinginASP.NETMVC/) to understand how you can capture errors. After exception is captured, you can log it with:

```
Logger.ErrorException(message, exception);
```